# Long laser pulse with broad spectral range

Tags: fourier-transform, laser, chirp

In the real time code I use for numerical time propagation, usually we use laser pulses with a Gaussian envelop and a central frequency. To obtain a pulse with a broad spectral range (few eV) very short laser pulses need to be selected (sub fs).

I'm looking for a laser pulse with a broad spectral range (again few eV) which is also longer than 10 fs. One option would be to use chirped pulses. Are there alternatives, i.e. non chirped pulses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the above answer, without chirping the pulse, the bandwidth $\Delta \omega$ and the time duration of the pulse $\Delta t$ are forced to have fixed product. $\Delta \omega \Delta t = \alpha $. However the value of such $ \alpha $ depends on the pulse shape. See for example here: [Book Ultrafast Optics, Chapter 2, Section 8](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electro-Optics/Book%3A_Ultrafast_Optics_(Kaertner)/02%3A_Maxwell-Bloch_Equations/2.08%3A_Pulse_Shapes_and_Time-Bandwidth_Products)

Reported values of $\alpha$ do not change much, however this probably depends also on how $\Delta \omega$ and $\Delta t$ are defined. However, for my original problem, i.e. numerical simulations, moving from a Gaussian (in time) envelop to a rectangular (in time) envelop has a huge impact since the frequency window of the Gaussian envelop goes down exponentially, while the one of the rectangular envelop goes down as $1/\omega$

Comment: I previously did an edit to the above answer, but it seems it was deleted. I add the info which was there as another answer. Please let me know if I should do otherwise.

Comment: I declined the edit because it was out of scope of the question. Its no problem to add this here additionally, but the question was: "is there another way to have pulses longer than transform limit other than chirping", to which I gave an answer. Going below the transform limit time-bandwidth is of different scope: you can go below if you are willing to live with the added temporal distortions in the wings of the pulse. However its better to do amplitude shaping than phase shaping for shorter pulses.

Comment: Well, my question wasn't "is it possible overcome the transform limit" but "is it possible, without chirping, to overcome the time limit I have now using Gaussians" . Changing the profile helps (I see your point on the distortions on the wings). Anyway, thank you very much for all the answers, they helped a lot in clarifying the question.

Answer (score 1):

As the transform limited pulse duration is set by the bandwidth, and your requirement is of a bandwidth that has a transform limit below 10 fs, then there is no other choice other than chirping the pulses to obtain longer pulses.

As you specified bandwidth in energy units, central frequency does not matter for the transform limit pulse duration.

Comment: Thanks. Is this (i.e. chirping pulses) also what is done experimentally when generating "supercontinuum pulses"?

Comment: Yes and no. The pulses that exit a supercontinuum generation system will be chirped due to the process, not because one actively chirps the pulses. Depending on the type of supercontinuum generation the chirp can be 1000s of times the transform limit or only a few times.

Comment: Ok, just one last comment, to see if I understand this point on super-continuum pulses. Suppose that in an optical  setup a supercontinuum chirped pulse, which spans 2 eV and is about 100 fs long in time,  is used to probe the sample. Chirp is just a side effect, so if it were possible to remove the chirp without loosing spectral range, this would correspond to roughly a 2 fs probe pulse. It is probably almost impossible to remove the chirp from the pulse, but I can try to remove it post-processing the signal. In case I'd actually have a signal probed with 2fs time resolution. Is this correct?

Comment: No, you cannot post-process the chirp away. Its a physical property of your light. The spectrum of a photography flash lamp could easily generate 2-fs pulses. Yet the flash is several ms long (aside from the coherence). Well, if your interaction with the sample is 100fs long, than that is your time resolution. There might be some special and complex gating/interferometric technique that I do not know of that might be able to recover information down to the transform limit. But it would require at least 2 pulses and be time-resolved (data acquired for different delays between the 2).

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Pump and probe experiments where the cirp from the probe signal is removed from the 2d maps. Although you cannot really go down to 2 fs time resolution. Usually experimentalists would say that the probe time resolution is not limiting what you can resolve. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear enough, and I don't want to mislead you. I work in the field and pretty much know most techniques to retrieve information from pump-probe signals. You cannot simply take away the chirp from data sets. So far, in pump-probe, the best resolution is down to the shortest pulse of your pump probe setup (if one is 100 and the other 10, your resolution is 10). That is simply because you cannot isolate the interaction, a 100 fs probe will probe an evolution of your sample that is 100 fs long.

Comment: Ok. We are going a bit out of topic. It should be probably part of another question "is it possible to remove chirp from the signal of a P&p experiment." Anyway, I checked this point with my experimental collaborators. They can indeed go below 100 fs despite having a chirped 100 fs (or even longer) white pulse, but they need to do "grating over an array of photodetectors". Hope it makes sense.